# Creating a Time to Live index using MongoVue

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

MongoVue 1.6.9.0

I am using MongoVue to connect to MongoDB.
I need to create a TTL index on a collection which I tried to create using "Add New Index".
Once I create the index by adding

```
{ "createdOn": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 }
```

The learn shell shows the query executed

```
db.ClaimDetails.ensureIndex({ "createdAt" : 1 },{ "name" : "TTL2" });
```

bu the expireAfterSeconds is not created.

Can you help on how to put expireAfterSeconds using MongoVue.

Thanks in advance.

Mongo 2.6.4,[image]